# How to create multiple laravel projects in wamp 2.4 (Windows 7 32 bit)

Tags: php, laravel, windows-7, wamp

New to Laravel and PHP Programming. I have successfully installed Laravel 4 framework on my wamp. Now, I would like to import an existing Laravel project (configured using Apache and compiled with VC11) into my own local wamp 2.4 (PHP 5.4.16). So, my question would be

```
1. Is it possible for wamp to host 2 laravel projects on the same machine?
2. If yes to (1), then what would I need to configure this or is there a guide/tutorial on this?
3. If no to (1), would I need to reconfigure the original settings of the existing laravel project for it to work on my wamp?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is this: Wamp have a www directory in c:\wamp\www\ so you can simply create two project, for example c:\wamp\www\project1 and c:\wamp\www\project2 and import the project with Composer.

Comment: Thanks for the Composer import tip! I just copy paste the entire project into my www folder. So far, I can see the index.php file display. I assume it's fine for now but it's an empty laravel framework with nothing being built yet. Not sure if I will run into trouble later for not using Composer to import the project.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution using WAMP so if that is vital to your setup then this answer would be unhelpful, however an alternative would be to use [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com). This allows you to run a development environment that closely mirrors that of your deployment environment, which will save you from hassle when deploying as to why things aren't working and supports multiple sites.

I believe laravel have their own official, easy to use vagrant files called [homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/homestead).

Comment: Wamp was already installed on my machine, so I just used it instead of configuring it to the development. Thanks for the tip on homestead. I will look into it and see how I can use it for deployment in the future.